# JAXB Marshaller cannot set property for CharacterEscapeHandler

Tags: java, jaxb

We have a non-Spring application running with JDK 11.  In our pom.xml file we have the following:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>jakarta.xml.bind</groupId>
    <artifactId>jakarta.xml.bind-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.3</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxb-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.3</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jaxb</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxb-runtime</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.3</version>
</dependency>
```

We have code to to a Marshalling of a java object to xml as follows:

```
Marshaller marshaller = JAXBContext.newInstance(Ratings.class).createMarshaller();
marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_NO_NAMESPACE_SCHEMA_LOCATION, schemaLocation);
marshaller.setProperty(CharacterEscapeHandler.class.getName(), 
                        new CDATACharacterEscapeHandler());
        
StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
marshaller.marshal(ratings, writer);        
return writer.toString();
```

The code fails when we try to set the CharacterEscapeHandler.  We get the following error:

```
Caused by: javax.xml.bind.PropertyException: name: 
com.mycode.server.utils.CDATACharacterEscapeHandler value: 
com.mycode.server.utils.CDATACharacterEscapeHandler@74921b67
at javax.xml.bind.helpers.AbstractMarshallerImpl.setProperty
(AbstractMarshallerImpl.java:343)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.MarshallerImpl.setProperty
(MarshallerImpl.java:516)
```

I can tell you about our custom CDATACharacterEscapeHandler as follows:

```
// this is the only class that I could find with this name.
//  even when I pull in com.sun.xml.bind.jaxb-core 2.3.0
import org.glassfish.jaxb.core.marshaller.CharacterEscapeHandler;

public class CDATACharacterEscapeHandler implements CharacterEscapeHandler  {
    @Override
    public void escape(char[] ch, int start, int length, boolean isAttVal, Writer writer) throws IOException
    {
      ...
    }
}
```

You can see that our CDATACharacterEscapeHandler extends a standard CharacterEscapeHandler.

I've spent about 5 hours research between StackOveflow and the Internet in general.   I have been to the JAXB official site.  And I know I have tried a lot of things such as:

```
marshaller.setProperty(CDATACharacterEscapeHandler.class.getName(), new CDATACharacterEscapeHandler());

marshaller.setProperty("com.sun.xml.bind.characterEscapeHandler", new CDATACharacterEscapeHandler());
```

And nothing seems to work.  I one point I tried moving to the latest 3.0.2 versions of code, and that also did not work.   It made more of a hassle because the java.xml.bind package was changed to jakarta.xml.bind and I didn't want to update all our code at this time.   That can be another effort later.

I have bookmarked other questions on Stackoverflow where someone got answers, and I tried those efforts, but nothing here seemed to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On my side I have to change my pom.xml config with:

```xml
<!-- JAXB -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>jakarta.xml.bind</groupId>
    <artifactId>jakarta.xml.bind-api</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jaxb</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxb-runtime</artifactId>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
```

by changing the original scope of the `jaxb-runtime` from `runtime` to `compile` and then in my code I have something like:

```java
if (cdata) {
    marshaller.setProperty(CharacterEscapeHandler.class.getName(),
            new CharacterEscapeHandler() {
                @Override
                public void escape(char[] ac, int i, int j, boolean flag, Writer writer) throws IOException {
                    // some code here
                    writer.write(ac, i, j);
                    
                }
            });
}
```

and I still have the sonar alert that I am using

```
import com.sun.xml.bind.marshaller.CharacterEscapeHandler;
```

in my imports, but I did not found a better way doing it with java >= 11 (currently working in Java 17).

Answer (score 3):

Updating marshaller property key from `com.sun.xml.internal.bind.marshaller.CharacterEscapeHandler` to `org.glassfish.jaxb.characterEscapeHandler` may resolve the issue for new JAXB glassfish implementation. Worked for Java 17.

```
marshaller.setProperty("org.glassfish.jaxb.characterEscapeHandler", new NoEscapeHandler());
```

Comment: see glassfish jaxb-runtime.jar org.glassfish.jaxb.runtime.v2.runtime.MarshallerImpl for the property names

Comment: I've tried everything but this is the only solution that works in Quarkus 3 for the included JAXB 4.0.

Comment: I had to comment the line you are mentioning for Java17. Then it is working...